# Best practices for Android Git branching

Tags: android, git, branch, config

Help settle an argument,

In an Android project, our AndroidManifest.xml has an ENV variable to build the apk to look at the correct env for S3 and other stuff.

We have 3 separate Git branches, dev, qa, and prod. Should the dev and qa manifest files point to prod env?

Answer (score 1):

No, If you are using Android Studio, this is handled by configuring your build types.

Also is not good practice use a branch for the differents environments, and also if you are using secret ids also not should be committed this.

You can create 3 buildTypes, debug, qa and release, So only when you signed an app, Will be with the env vars of production.

[Link about buildTypes](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/build-variants.html)